# Intercept Barcode Scanner, Pass to Application with Focus When Done?

Tags: c#, windows, input, io

Is there a way to intercept USB Barcode Scanner input, utilize it, then pass it on to the application that has focus?

We currently use Barcode scanners load order shipment information into Endicia and FedEx. When those applications start up, the lookup field is given focus. When you scan a barcode, the text is passed into the field, and then those applications look up the rest of the customer information. This process works great.

Now we are trying to limit pick errors by comparing the actual order weight with what it should be. In order to do this real-time, I need to intercept the scanner input and use it check the calculated weight in the database against the actual scale weight. If it is off by a significant margin I want to display a warning message.

I also need to be able to then pass the barcode back to the correct field in the original application that had focus so it can look up the shipment data.

Has anyone done something like this? Can you point me to some resources on intercepting input then bubbling it back up to the field that had focus?

Note: This is in a Windows environment. I'm most familiar with C#, but VB.net would also work.

Comment: Think of the barcode scanner is a keyboard, except that when you scan something it sends the barcode to the computer. The reason the other programs open up and give focus to a textbox is so that when the scanner scans something it goes into that field. Are you wanting the scanned barcode to go to multiple places?

Comment: Rob, going multiple places would be fine. I basically need it to do what it currently does, but also have a way of capturing the input in another program to do some extra processing.

Comment: From reading other comments on answers.. you could save the information to a small file then return an exit code from the application that gathers this data that will notify you that it has been created sucessfully. Your other program(s) then will have confidence that a file can be found containing the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a computer, a barcode scanner is just like a keyboard, without the keys. When you scan a barcode, the scanner converts the barcode into keyboard input. In order to capture the input in a second program, you'd need to use a keyboard hook.

Look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) and [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook). You can make a program that uses one of these keyboard hooks and any data you scan with your barcode scanner will get routed to your program too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to send keystrokes to the currently focused window, as long as that window has a lower or equal integrity level. Plenty of information on the web for calling that function from C#.

Many barcode readers can be configured to put an arbitrary keycode at the start of a scan. Have it output a code that you have defined as a hotkey on your PC to start up your program or bring it to the foreground. Once you've input the barcode, destroy or hide your window to restore focus to the previous application and call SendInput.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. We already add a keycode at the end of the input so that the barcode submits. Hadn't though about adding one before it to open another program. Wondering if the program that is being fired will open fast enough to receive the rest of the input? Or is that not a concern?

Comment: @Sam, yes it's a concern. You might also be able to configure in a delay.

Comment: I think I'll try to piggy-back off this idea with a keylogger. Basically, prepend the output with something like F7, buffer the input until we hit the appended Enter, then use the value between F7 & Enter to do my processing.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a windows Form and in the Load event of the form, give focus to the TextBox that the barcode should be entered into. Then in the TextChanged event of the TextBox, do whatever processing you need to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx

Misunderstood the question, try googling a little bit:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5213874a-603e-4378-835d-f6488f382d47

Comment: But how do I pass the input back to the correct field in the original application?

Comment: You probably can't (easily) unless the "original" application is one that you have the source code to. You will just need to scan a second time.

Comment: I didn't think that was the case which is why I was asking about intercepting. Thanks though.