# Possible to keep excel file as active window even if I am scrolling through the internet - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have recently completed a wonderful barcode system which uses wired scanners. They scan into an ActiveX textbox in excel and use the barcode value to look at a series of cases to perform functions before blanking out the textbox for the next entry.

I must have the excel window selected at all times in order for the barcode scan to work. If I am not in the excel window and active the scan will not register. I must purchase another computer if i cant get this done! Not a big deal, but money is money.

I have no python, or other experience. It seems like this thread might be of some help.
[Python and keeping excel barcode active link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823874/can-i-keep-the-terminal-as-the-active-window-even-if-its-in-the-background)

I know SAS, VBA, and some SQL. That's about it

Any help or insight would be magnificent!

Regards

Comment: You can always keep excel on top using APIS but AFAIK, You can't have 2 windows active at the same time in windows. The moment, you start browsing, excel will deactivate even while staying on top.

Comment: A helper program for redirecting the input from a specific usb-device might help, maybe combined with a virtual desktop solution so the window stays on top and the browser can stay on top on a second "desktop" too

Comment: You can always keep a PC or a Tablet dedicated for the barcode application? Do you really need to browse at the same time?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15686544/6608395) might be of some help

Comment: Here's another solution: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2030-keep-excel-window-on-top.html. This will keep the window on top, but not necessarily active.

Comment: Siddharth, I may end having to get a dedicated PC or tablet, ultimately I am not sure which processor I would need (i5, i6, i7) and how many GbH (maybe above 3?), or GB (Maybe 12)? I would have up to 6 scanners scanning into a USB hub, at most all of the scans (6) might happen once every 30 seconds, mainly different allotments of 5 minute spans. Each is independent of the other, but I want the system to be able to handle up to 6 scans in less than one second from 6 scanners.

Comment: Michael, that is a great link! I am assuming I can look into C# and download a source and build a hook for say this  `  and have the barcode register as a ` and alert the excel window?   Ryan, thank you for the input!